# Tensorflow translate.py import error: No module named translate

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to run Tensorflow's translate.py from a python console rather than through bazel -build, but I get an error at these two lines:

```
from tensorflow.models.rnn.translate import data_utils
from tensorflow.models.rnn.translate import seq2seq_model

ImportError: No module named translate
```

I've checked the folder to see that the "**init**.py" file is there, but python seems to think there is no such module as translate. 
How can i fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is to navigate to folder containing the translate module and running it. You can also download the translate module to any other place and run it. However, don't forget to change the above lines to:

```
from translate import data_utils
from translate import seq2seq_model
```

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this issue by removing all the `from tensorflow.models.rnn.translate` statements, leaving just

```
import data_utils
import seq2seq_model
```

in `translate.py` and

```
import data_utils
```

in `seq2seq_model.py`.